# My web host is attaching code to my php echo

Tags: php

Hey good day fellow developers. I wrote some PHP code to return the current day of the week, however every time I echo anything my web host is attaching its own script to it and its coming back in my ajax response text.

What would you recommend I do. Thanks in advance (:

Thursday

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
```

That's the response am getting, the current day which is Thursday but look at the code they attached.

```
<?php
   echo date("l");
?>
```

Comment: *"my web host is attaching its own script to it and its coming back in my ajax response text"* - Being what? - *"What would you recommend I do"* Try disabling it from the control panel. It's probably their way of using stats.

Comment: `<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->` there you go; I was right ^

Comment: I just wanna test out some php code.

Comment: Then just test it on your local machine. Or find another freehost that doesn't add analytics.

Comment: I was right about my first comment where they are most likely using that for their own stats, or that there is an option in the control panel to disable it. I have seen that before and for a site I work on also.

Comment: Thanks for the advice very helpful, am at work so I don't have a localhost installed on this machine.

Comment: Oh, if your work is not related to programming, I imagine they wouldn't allow you to install xampp or something. I don't like to advertise but [google provides free hosting](http://appspot.com) without any of that analytical garbage.

Comment: ok I got it work, what I did is that i used javascript substr function to only look for the first 8 letters in the response text

Comment: Check the PHP configuration to see if it has `auto_prepend_file` enabled. Disable that.

Comment: @KasciqueLowmans That's a pretty nifty workaround. Careful not getting too attached to your project however, one day you might migrate your project and then you'll have to remove all these hacks you put in.

Comment: @DaveChen Yes that's true, but I just want to test it out.